# Spread points equally

Tags: algorithm, grouping

This is more an algorithm than a development question.
I have many locations in a country (represented by geographical coordinates) and would like to group them so that each group covers a same area (the amount of different areas is fixed), and that each group roughly contains the same number of locations.

What would be the best method to reach this ?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific on what exactly the 'area' is and what you mean by "the amount of different areas". Here http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs345a/slides/12-clustering.pdf seems to be a survey on different clustering algorithms.

Comment: The [Ham sandwich theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ham_sandwich_theorem#Discrete_and_computational_geometry_versions) might be of use.

Comment: To add some explanation to my question: Basically I have a country, points of sale in the country and sales reps in the country that need to cover the points of sale. I want to allocate the same area (in km2) to each sales rep in order to ensure that they all roughly have the same amount of work. I know the gsm coordinates of each point of sale in the country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok let's define things (in pseudocode):

```
location: (double x-coord, double y-coord)
```

that is, every location is just two numbers. Let's say you have `M` locations.

```
group: array of (array of locations)
```

so that `group[i]` is an array that contains the locations of the i-th group.
Now, you know beforehand that you will end up with a fixed amount of groups (if i understood correctly what you are asking), let's call it N. So every group will have roughly `M/N` locations.
Now, your main problem is that you cannot order couples of numbers (ie complex numbers are not ordinable) but here is what i would do:

1. construct a matrix `matrix[i][j]` so that every cell contain a
   location. For my idea to work you have to make that (let's borrow
   some OO notation):

   - `matrix[i][j].x <= matrix[i+1][j].x`
   - `matrix[i][j].y <= matrix[i][j+1].y`.

   In order for this to work some cells may be empty. Just discard them in the next phase.
2. Then you define a group as a submatrix that contain only adjacent locations (or locations that you can reach travelling only on adjacent locations). So you start a for cycle (java/c notation) `for(int i=0; i<N; i++)` and inside you add element to `group[i]` until `group[i].length` reaches `M/N`; then you go to the next `i`. I would iterate the matrix using something like (0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(0,2),(2,0),(2,1),(1,2),(2,2)... but you can implement it in some different way (for example taking into account the difference between coordinates so that you group together only "close" locations but that depends on what you need.

Your problem is not easy but if you only need a rough grouping it can be done easily.